# Xamarin Android axml Designer, System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Note: This occurs with the most recent version of Visual Studio Mac and the latest Xamarin tools installed.

I started to work on an older Xamarin Android project that I've been maintaining over the past few years. It's been a long time since I've made any UI changes to the application and there was a minor adjustment I needed to make in order to add some additional information to the screen. I opened up the axml layout of screen I needed to modify. When doing so, the designer view displayed the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path1
>     at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2, System.String path3) [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:849 
>     at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject+<>c.b__118_0 (System.String l) [0x00000] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/DesignerProject.cs:532 
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00036] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.cs:365 
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext () [0x0004e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs:146 
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2[TSource,TResult].ToList () [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/SelectMany.cs:257 
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs:30 
>     at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.GetLibraryProjectThemes () [0x00037] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/DesignerProject.cs:531 
>     at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.GetIsProjectTheme (System.String themeName) [0x0000e] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/DesignerProject.cs:544 
>     at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerSessionParams.GetData (Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession session, Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidRenderSession renderer) [0x00154] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/DesignerSessionParams.cs:209 
>     at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidRenderSession+d__115.MoveNext () [0x00224] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/AndroidRenderSession.cs:783

I initially thought there must be some kind of Syntax issue with the newer Xamarin tools but when I tried creating a brand new Android Layout, I received the same error for the designer. The Xamarin Android new layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Because of this, I'm thinking that there has to be some kind of setup option that I'm missing due to this being an older project. Perhaps something to do with the incorrect designer tool path being assigned somewhere? Has anyone come across this error or have some ideas on what to check?

**Edit:**
Additional Info
Android SDK Location:

> /Users/mrnope/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx

Android NDK Location:

> /Users/mrnope/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-ndk/android-ndk-r14b

Java SDK (JDK) Location:

> /usr

[image: Files found]
Android SDK Tools:
[image: Android SDK Tools]
SDK Platforms:
[image: SDK Platforms]

Comment: I have the same problem...I've tried absolutely everything. I can sometimes get it to work temporarily if I delete all of the support library packages (which means I can't actually build the project because it depends on them). As soon as I re-add them or try building the project, I get the same exception again.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that Visual Studio cannot find the proper Android SDK path and/or the Platform Tools.

> Tools -> Option -> Android Settings

And insert the proper path there, then I would double-check that the Platform Tools are installed correctly and are on the same version of the SDK.

> Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager

Comment: I looked at these but as far as I can tell everything looks correct. I've added some additional information and screenshots from reviewing this information.

Comment: Update your Android SDK Tools to the version 27

Comment: I have the latest SDK Build tools installed. I've tried toggling the "Android SDK Tools" to version 26.1.1 but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Not sure why you cannot choose the version 27. But I suggest you uninstall the Android SDK 27 and Build Tools 27, and select the Android SDK Tools to version 26. You should have the SAME version of Android SDK, Build Tools and Tools.

Comment: As far as I can tell from searching, there is no version 27 of the "Android SDK Tools". I switch everything to look at version 26, removed all other versions but there was no change.